# Extract odometry and map from .db file on Tango

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

@matlabbe, I have saved a map on Tango with .db format. Now, I would like to get the odometry data from it. Is it possible?

Also, when I try to get the map in .pgm format like the one you described [here](http://answers.ros.org/answers/217100/revisions/), I get the following error:

```
[FATAL] (2016-07-04 10:00:06.287) util3d.cpp:252::cloudFromDepth() Condition (imageDepth.rows % decimation == 0) not met! [rows=90 decimation=4]

ERROR: service [/publish_map] responded with an error: [FATAL] (2016-07-04 10:00:06.287) util3d.cpp:252::cloudFromDepth() Condition (imageDepth.rows % decimation == 0) not met! [rows=90 decimation=4]
```

Do I have to change something?

Now, by changing  `cloud_decimation` for the following map:

[image: image description]

I can save the map, but the result looks like this:
[image: image description]

It seems I am missing some data. Is it possible to improve it?

**Update:**
Now by using `rosservice call /publish_map 1 1 0` I get the following map, I still miss some data.
[image: image description]

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238705/extract-odometry-and-map-from-.db-file-on-tango/) by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-05**:
If you are using `publish_map` service, make sure you set `global` param to `true`: `$ rosservice call /publish_map 1 1 0` (second param is for `optimized` and last one for `graph only`) to get the global map. I think what is shown in your grid map is the local map.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-06**:
Can you share the database? I just tried with a database created on Tango and I can get the full occupancy grid map.

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-07-07**:
Here is the database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jesjrrsgxi8fe5/bigmap.db?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

By default [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) decimates by 4 RGB-D images to avoid creating very large point clouds. As depth images are already small for Tango, you can set `cloud_decimation` to `1`:

```
 <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
    <param name="cloud_decimation" value="1"/>
    ...
 </node>
```

If you are only interested on odometry poses, open the database with standalone app `$ rtabmap`, "File" -> "Open Database..." and click "Edit" -> "Download graph-only" (choose **not optimized** to get odometry poses without graph corrections), then "File" -> "Export poses...".

You may also like the [rtabmap-databaseViewer](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Tools#database-viewer) tool to inspect the odometry (neighbor) links in the database (View->Show Constraints).

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the database. I couldn't reproduce the exact error you have (showing only a part of the map) but it helped me to [fix a bug](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/commit/4cd870571081f7aab9ad66dd4330ae128ce0c3d6) when generating the projection maps with data from Tango (depth and rgb images are not the same size and the calibration wasn't updated).

Workaround for current binaries 0.11.7 (Hack: we subscribe at the same time to cloud_map to create XYZRGB clouds instead of XYZ clouds for the projection):

```
$ roscore
$ rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap _database_path:=~/Downloads/bigmap.db
$ rostopic hz /cloud_map
$ rosrun map_server map_saver map:=proj_map
$ rosservice call /publish_map 1 1 0
```

With the fix on 0.11.8:

```
$ roscore
$ rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap _database_path:=~/Downloads/bigmap.db
$ rosrun map_server map_saver map:=proj_map
$ rosservice call /publish_map 1 1 0
```

Note that `cloud_decimation` can stay at `4` since we apply decimation on the RGB image size instead of the depth image size.

[image: image description]

```
image: map.pgm
resolution: 0.050000
origin: [-37.192123, -27.229282, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-07-05**:
@matlabbe, When I do "Export poses", in the text file I have 12 columns in each row, what does each stand for? The first three are the pose in the x, y, z and ...?

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-07-05**:
Also, can I get time as well?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-05**:
You can try the RGB-D SLAM export format, which is "stamp x y z qx qy qz qw". The RAW format is the transformation matrix 3x4: "r00 r01 r02 tx r10 r11 r12 ty r20 r21 r22 tz"

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-07-06**:
@matlabbe Is there anyway to get the roll pitch yaw from the data directly? When I look at the data through rtabmap-databaseViewer tool, the data for the yaw angle is what I want. But, when I transform the data from qx qy qz qw to rpy I don't get the same thing.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-06**:
Ah yeah, to comply to RGB-D SLAM benchmark tool, the poses are transformed in rgbd-slam's world frame. I would recommend the RAW format then, and transform the rotation matrix:
r00 r01 r02
r10 r11 r12
r20 r21 r22
to euler angles.

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-07-06**:
@matlabbe thanks for the quick answer. Now, I am getting rpy correctly.

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-07-07**:
Is there a way to get the rpy angles from quaternion data instead of rotation matrix? I would like to compare something from the data I get on Kinect in Rviz with Tango.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-08**:
You may want to kook at this: http://answers.ros.org/question/50113/transform-quaternion/

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-07-11**:
@matlabbe Thanks for your explanation. I have the map correctly now.